# How do I set up sftp to work with wordpress to allow me to upload images?

Tags: wordpress, ssh, apache2, sftp

On my server I'm using a RSA key with a password to connect via shell or sftp. I've disabled passwords all together.

I'm using php 7 and wordpress 4.8.

Now I'm running into the problem that when I want to upload an image to wordpress, it won't let me. I am using WP CLI to update all of my plugins, but it doesn't help me with the file upload.

All of the ssh/sftp plugins I've found are over 2 years old and don't seem to be helping. Has anyone fixed this problem yet?

Comment: RFA?  What's that?  Google didn't yield anything meaningful.  Did you mean RSA key?  As in an RSA SecurID one-time password device?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn Yes I did mean RSA. Sorry.